# Sumo Traffic Simulator Edges Aggregate data

Tags: sumo, traffic-simulation

I'm using Sumo Traffic Simulator to get aggregate data about delay time and congestion for each edge. I'm trying to use edgeData parameter.

I'm using the below config file (osm.sumocfg):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- generated on 2022-08-24 18:03:24 by Eclipse SUMO sumo Version 1.14.1
-->

<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/sumoConfiguration.xsd">

    <input>
        <net-file value="osm.net.xml"/>
        <route-files value="osm.passenger.trips.xml"/>
        <additional-files value="osm.poly.xml"/>
    </input>

    <processing>
        <ignore-route-errors value="true"/>
    </processing>

    <routing>
        <device.rerouting.adaptation-steps value="18"/>
        <device.rerouting.adaptation-interval value="10"/>
    </routing>
    
    <additional>
        <edgeData id="myEdges1" file="osm.edges.xml"/>
    </additional>
    
    <report>
        <verbose value="true"/>
        <duration-log.statistics value="true"/>
        <no-step-log value="true"/>
    </report>

    <gui_only>
        <gui-settings-file value="osm.view.xml"/>
    </gui_only>

</configuration>
```

However, after running: sumo -c osm.sumocfg , no files are created for osm.edges.xml.

Any advice, please?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The section

```
<additional>
    <edgeData id="myEdges1" file="osm.edges.xml"/>
</additional>
```

needs to go into a separate file, let's call it `edgedata.xml` and then you need to refer to it in your config as additional file:

```
<additional-files value="edgedata.xml,osm.poly.xml"/>
```